# Jquery to iterate through multiple sections and fields of table

Tags: php, jquery

Here is what I'm doing.

I have a set of divs. Each set of divs can contain a section header and a list of items. Each item has a price associated with it. So item 1 under section Demolition has a price of 150.00. Item 2 under section Demolition has a price of 200.00. Next to each item is an input field that the user can type in a numeric value. That value is then multiplied by the item price. So next to item 1(150.00) is a field where I enter 2. In the next div I then display the total. So 150.00 x 2 = 300.00.

I can do this for each item under the section. I then sum the entire items into one global price next to the sections.

Here is a sample of what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".demolition_num").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function(){
      calculateDemSum();
    });
  });
});


function calculateDemSum() {
   var sum = 0;
   $(".demolition_num").each(function(){
     if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.lenth != 0){
        var unitCost = $(".unit_cost1").text();
        var _parent = $(this).parent();
        var total = _parent.prev().html();
        sum += parseFloat(this.value * total);
        var subtotal = this.value * total;
        $(_parent).next().html(this.value * total);
     }
     else if (this.value.length !=0){
     }
   });

   $(".cost1").text(sum.toFixed(2));
   $("#cost1").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

You can view all the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pmetzger/Xeu2T/3/

As you can see in the jquery that right now I have to call each section independently 
of the others since I do not want to calculate all of the fields, just the one I'm modifying.

So the question is, can I avoid having to add each sections input type id as the key up to trigger the calculations and make sure the totals get placed correctly?

Note: This code could be duplicated, but the data associated is going to be different. So on the next clients list it might not be Demolition, but Demo and so forth.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a couple of pointers:

1. You don't need to bind events within an `each()` loop, simply
   binding it to a standard selector will bind to all elements that fit
   that selector.
2. You also have multiple `<tr>` elements with the same id.
3. You don't need a `size` attribute on hidden tags

New working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nN2eM/1/) and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Bind the event
    $("#calc").on("keyup", "input[type='text']", function()
    {
        calculateSum(this);
    });
});

function calculateSum(element)
{
    var sum = 0;
    var $this = $(element);
    var targetClass = $this.attr("class");

    // Process each element with the same class
    $("." + targetClass).each(function()
    {
        var thisVal = $(this).val();

        // Count invalid entries as 0
        if(isNaN(thisVal) || thisVal.length === 0)
        {
            thisVal = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            thisVal = parseFloat(thisVal);
        }

        // Get the unit cost and calculate sub-total
        var unitCost = parseFloat($(this).parent().prev("td.unit_cost").text());
    var subTotal = thisVal * unitCost;
    sum += subTotal;
        $(this).parent().next("td").text(subTotal);
    });

    var $item = $this.closest("tr").prevAll(".item").first();
    $item.find("input.section_cost").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    $item.find("td.section_cost").text(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Note that I have modified your HTML slightly - I changed the multiple `<tr id="item">` to use classes, I moved where these rows were to better target your subsection totals, I added classes to the subsection totals (both hidden inputs and displayed values), I added a class to your unit value fields and I added an id to the table.